# Connecting nichrome wire to copper wire

Tags: wire, interconnect

Can I attach a nichrome wire to a copper wire using a crimp connector like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYonU.jpg)? Is there an easier way to achieve this? Like soldering? The nichrome wire is expected to get as hot as 70 °C.

Comment: Crimp is normally how I've seen it done (in space heaters, etc), but I'd probably use an uninsulated connector and some high-temp standoffs to secure it.

Comment: I wonder if a small spot-welder would work.

Comment: Commerical heaters that I have seen used spot welded connections to the nicrome. Crimp might work, but I would worry about oxidation over time ruining the connection.

Comment: Forget solder.  IMO crimp or spot welding are the only practical durable options.   Ceramic terminal block maybe, but I'd not use it for long-term.   Screws can get loose due to thermal cycling.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use a crimp because the nichrome wire could get hot enough to melt the solder. There are also crimp on lugs (that go to a fastener) without plastic that could melt that would probably be a better option (or remove the plastic). It really depends on how hot you plan on getting the wire but at 70 °C it probably wouldn't be that big of a deal what you use. Solder melts at over 200 °C so 70 °C would be fine to use solder.

Comment: There’s also terminal blocks with ceramic bodies

Comment: Good point, especially if your not DIY

Comment: Will regular 63/37 solder or lead-free equivalent even wet nichrome wire?

Comment: Do not use solder! The 70 degree assumption is for optimal case. If anything goes wrong, one can get high temperatures that can melt the solder, making an even higher resistance joint and possibly causing a fire. I would use spot-weld or crimped nickel-coated (tinned) copper (not bare copper, as crimped bare copper still oxidizes, eventually making a high-resistance joint.) If you want to strengthen either, you might be able to use brazing (like soldering, but using brass, a copper alloy) which might be a nice backup connection strategy, improving connection and the connection structure.